CSV column mutated in SQL table
I have this problem: I have imported a .csv file as a table in my SQL database and although the column that I'm interested in has values like 145.0 or 90.0 (in the .csv file), when I write a query and run it in order to display all the components of the table, I get values like 1450 and 90 instead.
How could I solve that problem?
PS: the data type of the column in the table is float

Could this be caused by a locale setting for numbers imports in your database software? For example, USA uses 1,234.00 but some other countries format it as 1.234,00. Just making a guess.

"some other countries" ??? WTF, some ?? (But the main message is probably TRUE)

I used the SQL Azure Import plugin to import a table of movies and depsite that the csv file had .0 values in the 'runtime' column  (like 145.0 and 90.0), the table that was imported made something like removing the floating point from all rows and printed results like 1450 and 900. I dont think it is related to the locale settings that you are talking about

You haven't provided enough information. Where is the CSV file coming from? Have you looked at it in a raw text editor? It may be that the data is imported correctly but was not exported correctly.

i checked the csv opening it with microsoft excel and wrote a script in the azure data studio. To be exact i run this query (Select * from movie;) and i saw that in the table printed the result registries in the runtime column are not as they should be

I specifically said to use a raw text editor like NotePad. You don't want to do that. So do what you want. (And if you don't address your comments to someone, they may not know that you responded.)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
